# How to handle pagination using python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I need help on how to use `python requests GET` to get data from api that have multiple page.

Lets say the api returns below response for `current_key=223132`

```
{
 "result":[
    {
    "aaa": 123,
    "bbb": 456,
    ...,
    ...
    }
  ],
  "next_key": 889182
 }
```

Next for `current_key=889182`

```
{
 "result":[
    {
    "aaa": 789,
    "bbb": 0,
    ...,
    ...
    }
  ],
  "next_key": 188192
 }
```

As you can see, the value of `next_key` indicates the next page/latest page with latest data. `current_key` indicates current page.
What I want to do now is every time I run `requests.get` it will always retrieve data for the next page.

I tried with below script but it always retrieve the data for `current_key=223132`

```
import requests
import json

data_set = []

url = "https://flespi.io/gw/channels/all/messages"
headers = {"Authorization":"MyToken"}
data = {"limit_count": 100, "limit_size": 1000}

query = {'data': json.dumps(data, separators=(',', ':'))}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=query)
```

I am thinking maybe I can put the parameter for page at `data` like this

```
data = {"limit_count": 100, "limit_size": 1000, "current_key": next_key}
```

but I think I might need to do `requests.get` without `current_key` parameter first before redo the `requests.get` with `current_key` parameter. In other words, get the value for `next_key` first then insert it on the next `requests.get`. That seems like a bad practice.

Is anyone have better idea?

Thank you for your help and suggestion. I really appreciate it.

Comment: can you list service API URI?

Comment: I'm sorry. what do you mean by listing the service API URI?

Comment: common solution for pagination is: `http://server/your/uri/?pageSize=10&pageNumber=1` 
Do you have something like that?

Comment: `https://flespi.io/gw/channels/all/messages?data=%7B%22curr_key%22%3A223132%2C%22limit_count%22%3A100%2C%22limit_size%22%3A1000%7D` this is the full url.as you can see `curr_key` is the current key which is the current page

Comment: and in your result you must have **total page** or **count**

Comment: unfortunately, in my result there is no **total page** or **count**. Like you can see from the api response, there is no such parameter. If there is I think I can just use loop but since there is none, I don't know what to do

Answer (score -2):

If your service does not provide **total page**, **count** for you:

use another solution

In this situation (that does not support pagination and Pager), you can implement `load more`, it requests data every time you need more data, like pinterest, instagram